# Dependencies issue while installing model card toolkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, mlmd

```
Model Card --> Model Card toolkit
```

I want to install a model card toolkit in my python virtual environment through this command:
**pip install model-card-toolkit**

```
 and I am facing this below issue, I have tried many times with different combinations but every time dependencies conflicts occurred. 

Collecting model-card-toolkit
ERROR: Cannot install model-card-toolkit==0.1.0, model-card-toolkit==0.1.1, model-card-toolkit==0.1.2, model-card-toolkit==0.1.3, model-card-toolkit==1.0.0, model-card-toolkit==1.1.0 and model-card-toolkit==1.2.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    model-card-toolkit 1.2.0 depends on tfx<1.6.0 and >=1.5.0
    model-card-toolkit 1.1.0 depends on ml-metadata<1.3.0 and >=1.2.0
    model-card-toolkit 1.0.0 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.27.0 and >=0.26.0
    model-card-toolkit 0.1.3 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.27.0 and >=0.26.0
    model-card-toolkit 0.1.2 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.27.0 and >=0.26.0
    model-card-toolkit 0.1.1 depends on absl-py<0.9 and >=0.7
    model-card-toolkit 0.1.0 depends on absl-py<0.9 and >=0.7

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

**I have these packages installed** 

    absl-py==1.0.0
    autopep8==1.6.0
    ml-metadata==0.13.1.dev0
    protobuf==3.19.3
    pycodestyle==2.8.0
    six==1.16.0
    toml==0.10.2


Can someone please help with which combination of packages should I have to install to resolve this issue?
```

Is there any other way to install the model card toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

[Possible cause:](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-card-toolkit/issues/202) `tfx` does not currently support Python 3.9. `model-card-toolkit` will not be compatible with Python 3.9 until `tfx` is updated.